# Pass complex object made of complex objects with cross references through POST form and EF into database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have basic object models with cross references

```cs
//Model in which I pass and gather data from view
public class ItemModel
{
    public BasicItem BasicItem;
    public FoodItem FoodItem;
    public LocalItem LocalItem;

    public ItemModel() 
        {
            BasicItem = new BasicItem();
            FoodItem = new FoodItem();
            LocalItem = new LocalItem();
        }
}

//And classes represents EF entities
public class BasicItem 
{
    ...//Multiple basic fields: int, string

    //EF references for PK-FK connection
    public FoodItem FoodItem { get; set; }
    public LocalItem LocalItem { get; set; }
}

public class LocalItem
{
    ...//Multiple basic fields: int, string

    //EF reference for PK-FK connection
    public BasicItem BasicItem { get; set; }

}

public class FoodItem
{
    ...//Multiple basic fields: int, string

    //EF reference for PK-FK connection
    public BasicItem BasicItem { get; set; }

}
```

And my view in basics seems like this

```html
@model ItemModel
...
<input required asp-for="BasicItem.Price" type="number" name="Price">
...
<input asp-for="FoodItem.Weight" type="number" name="Weight">
...
```

As now I connect it (so different entities have relation each to other) like this:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> ProductAdd(ItemModel ItemModel)
{
    if (ItemModel.BasicItem != null)
    {
        if (ItemModel.LocalItem != null)
        {
            ItemModel.BasicItem.LocalItem = ItemModel.LocalItem;
            ItemModel.LocalItem.BasicItem = ItemModel.BasicItem;
            await db.LocalItems.AddAsync(ItemModel.LocalItem);
        }

        //same for FoodItem

        await db.BasicItems.AddAsync(ItemModel.BasicItem);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

But data from form dosent bind to my ItemModel, so my code fails at point when it trying to Add new entity to db, but it has null fields(which null by default, but setuped in form).
Is there any way I can help bind this model to data Im entering?

As other way I can only see this: create plain model which will have all fields from Basic, Local and Food items and bind it in my *action*. But it will hurt a much, if I ever wanted to change one of this classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, we can divide my situation into 2 basic cases:

1. Creating new entities
2. Updating entities

In first case it's pretty simple and easy cause you can create new object, fill it up, setup relations (you can only setup relation in one object like `basicItem.FoodItem = foodItem`, you don't need to do `foodItem.BasicItem = basicItem`, cause *EF* will automatically connect them)  and send it to db, and it will work.

In second case, it's a little more complicated, cause in case to update data in db, you must get a related entity to a context. It's brings it's own limitations. And again you can have two approaches:

1. Create new object and manually (or through auto-mapper, but I didn't dig into this) overwrite fields of db related object at the end.
2. Fetch object from db at the beginning, pass it it through actions and change data on fly (if you want/need, you can even update db record on fly).

They are quite the same in a way, that you need to choose what field to update and write some code `dbFoodItem.Weight = userInput.Weight`.

So in my case I took second approach, and cause I collected data in multiple actions, I used *session* to data storage object between them.

Answer (score 0):

For you scenario , `BasicItem` has a one-to-one relationship with `LocalItem` and `FootItem`.When adding data into the database , you need to pay attention to that if the foreign key is nullable or exists and the order in which data is added to the primary table and child table .

Here is a working demo ,you could refer to :

**Model definition**

```
public class BasicItem
{
    public int BasicItemID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int FoodItemID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FoodItemID")]
    public FoodItem FoodItem { get; set; }
    public int LocalItemID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LocalItemID")]
    public LocalItem LocalItem { get; set; }
}
public class FoodItem
{
    public int FoodItemID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //public int BasicItemID { get; set; }
    public BasicItem BasicItem { get; set; }
}
public class LocalItem
{
    public int LocalItemID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //public int BasicItemID { get; set; }
    public BasicItem BasicItem { get; set; }
}
public class ItemModel
{
    public BasicItem BasicItem;
    public FoodItem FoodItem;
    public LocalItem LocalItem;

    public ItemModel()
    {
        BasicItem = new BasicItem();
        FoodItem = new FoodItem();
        LocalItem = new LocalItem();
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ProductAdd(ItemModel ItemModel)
    {
        if (ItemModel.BasicItem != null)
        {

            if (ItemModel.LocalItem != null)
            {

                await db.LocalItems.AddAsync(ItemModel.LocalItem);
                await db.FoodItems.AddAsync(ItemModel.FoodItem);
            }

            //same for FoodItem
            ItemModel.BasicItem.LocalItem = ItemModel.LocalItem;
            ItemModel.BasicItem.FoodItem = ItemModel.FoodItem;
            await db.BasicItems.AddAsync(ItemModel.BasicItem);

            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(ItemModel);
    }
```